# Did the Ewoks continue to think C-3PO was a god?

Tags: star-wars, droids, ewoks, return-of-the-jedi

In *Return of the Jedi*, our heroes are taken prisoner by Ewoks -- except for C-3PO:

> THREEPIO: I could be mistaken. They're using a very primitive dialect.  But I do believe they think I am some sort of god.

Later on, the Ewoks plan to cook and eat our heroes:

> THREEPIO: I'm rather embarrassed, General Solo, but it appears you are to be the 
>   main course at a banquet in my honor.

Luke uses the Force to lift up C-3PO and make him fly around. This makes the Ewoks afraid that C-3PO has magic powers, so they do as he says and free Luke and the others. C-3PO then tells them the story of the Rebellion, and they agree to help fight the Empire.

Did the Ewoks continue to think C-3PO was a god? Or did he explain that he was just a protocol droid?

If it's the former, then Threepio had a point: It **is** somewhat unethical to manipulate a Stone Age people by impersonating one of their gods, especially if you're persuading them to make war on the Galactic Empire.

Comment: As they intended to *kill and eat* our heroes, I'm inclined to think "sod 'em and their ethics."

Comment: @TZHX: Fair point, but it's a bit harsh on the cute infant Ewoks if the Rebellion loses, and the Empire conducts reprisals with extreme prejudice. I suppose the end justifies the means, and all that.

Comment: @TZHX Oh, the Ewoks were only small.  A couple of limbs should have done for a bang up feast. ;)

Comment: Weren't the Imperials already bothering the Ewoks? They probably would have killed them eventually.

Comment: “It is somewhat unethical to manipulate a Stone Age people by impersonating one of their gods” — alright, what are you, a Prime Directive policeman or something?

Comment: **unethical**??? These people just recently blew up a space station with 1 million people, overthrew (or tried to) a legitimate government, performed an extrajudicial hit on a local crime lord, and one of them joined an illegal traitorous cult and another was a drug trafficer! What do you expect, upstanding model citizens?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_VI:_Return_of_the_Jedi_(novel)), the Ewoks did indeed continue to believe that Threepio was a god, but that the decision to fight on the side of the Rebellion was taken largely because they'd shown themselves to be friends of the Ewoks ("*leafbrothers*") where the Empire had shown themselves to be enemies of the 'Great Forest' rather than simply because their god told them to:

> *Threepio translated for his friends: ‘Honorable Elders, we have this
>   night received a perilous, wondrous gift. The gift of freedom. This
>   golden god …’ - here Threepio paused in his translation just long
>   enough to savor the moment; then went on - ‘… **This golden god, whose
>   return to us has been prophesied since the First Tree, tells us now he
>   will not be our Master, tells us we are free to choose as we will** -
>   that we must choose; as all living things must choose their own
>   destiny. He has come, Honorable Elders, and he will go; no longer may
>   we be slaves to his divine guidance. We are free.*